# Is it possible to add margin between buttons in a collapsable button group without adding any margin around the group?

Tags: html, css

I have a button container with n buttons.

Example code:

```
<div class="button-group">
  <div class= button>
    First
  </div>
  <div class= button>
    Second
  </div>
</div>

.button-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.button {
  padding: 20px 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgQWmE

How can I add `10px` margin between these buttons?

The following limitations apply:

- The buttons can collapse at some unknown viewport width
- There should be no margin around the group of buttons
- I can not use grid as it is not supported in IE 11

Comment: only one row of buttons?

Comment: @user1283776 use custom grid

Comment: Use the age-old trick of countering the margins on the side by a negative margin on the container …? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqYRmO

Comment: @misorude: That is awesome, thanks! I didn't know about that age old trick. Here is your code pen but with vertical margin as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqYRmO

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `margin-right: 10px` to all the `.button` elements and then target the last child in the group and remove the 10px margin:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.button-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  padding: 20px 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group">
  <div class=button>
    First
  </div>
  <div class=button>
    Second
  </div>
</div>
```